# Cor da ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout

Gostaria de saber como posso trocar a cor da *ActionBar* dinamicamente ?

Já tentei pegar pela `getSupportActionBar` mais não consegui.

Comment: O que já tentou? Tem código de tentativas? Se sim, adicione na pergunta clicando em [edit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
```

Ou assim:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorBlack)));
```

Comment: Boa tarde Luiz, funcionou sim Como que posso setar a colorPrimaryDark também ?

Comment: Boa tarde Luiz, funcionou sim Como que posso setar a colorPrimaryDark também ?

Comment: Você não pode mudar a primary color dinamicamente. Ela faz parte de um tema e temas são imutáveis dinamicamente. Você pode é ter vários temas pré definidos e altera dinamicamente. Mas isso está fora do escopo da sua pergunta, se minha resposta lhe serviu, por favor, marque como certa.